# Flash Facebook app...loaded images are invisible...why?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, bitmap

Hi
Created a simple gallery in flash for a facebook application. Everything works fine locally, and when uploaded to our staging server the images seem to load but they are invisible.

I AM creating a LoaderContext file and passing true as a parameter so this isn't the issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
//CODE START
_lctx=new LoaderContext(true);
//or _lctx.checkPolicyFile = true;
_my_loader.load(new URLRequest(smallImg), _lctx);
//CODE END
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to know what's going on. Whether or not the LoaderContext even matters depends on how you're displaying the images: it shouldn't matter if you're adding the loader as a child, it will certainly matter if you're trying to get to the BitmapData.

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with images not loading with flex in the past.  I need some more details, but when I've had issues I found that loading the image into a new bitmap object worked ok:

```
            var imgReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(source+"");
            var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
                imgCompleteHandler);
            imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            imgLoader.load(imgReq);

            function imgCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void {
                var loader:LoaderInfo = evt.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
                var bmp:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;
                var bmd:BitmapData = bmp.bitmapData;
                image.source = new Bitmap(bmd);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what your are looking for.
We came across the same problem while developing a facebook app in flash. Turns out that we need a [Crossdomain.xml](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=28480) file to render images in staging.